# Google Charts: Column chart invert y axis

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to invert the y axis of my column chart so that lower numbers are displayed higher.

I have tried vAxis: { direction: -1 }

[image]

When I do this the columns come out of the top of the chart, I want the columns to come from the bottom of the chart and if they have a lower number they will be taller.

I read somewhere about negating the number and using number format to display them as positive but Im not sure how to do that.

I used the accepted answer to get what I wanted which was -

[image]

Edit:
I created my own scale by finding the biggest of my set of data, the biggest var. Biggest is the biggest value of my data set and the objective is to make it just a little bit bigger to start the bottom of the chart at that, so that column has a little height on the chart instead of 0 height. Quite hard coded but worked for my datasets.

```
if (biggest <= 15)
{
    biggest = 20;
} else if (biggest <= 45)
{
    biggest = 50;
} else if (biggest <= 70)
{
    biggest = 75;
} else
{   
    if (Math.ceil(biggest / 100) * 100 === biggest)
    {
        // Round up to the next nearest 100
        biggest = Math.ceil(biggest / 100) * 100 + 100;
    } else
    {
        // Round up to the nearest 100
        biggest = Math.ceil(biggest / 100) * 100;
    }
}
```

I then dived it into 5 equal sections.

```
var temp1 = (biggest / 5);
var temp2 = (biggest / 5) * 2;
var temp3 = (biggest / 5) * 3;
var temp4 = (biggest / 5) * 4;
```

Then added it to the chart like:

```
var options = {
    title: 'Rank Comparison',
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
    vAxis: {
        ticks: [
        // use object notation to provide y-axis labels
        {v: 0, f: biggest.toString()},
        {v: temp1, f: temp4.toString()},
        {v: temp2, f: temp3.toString()},
        {v: temp3, f: temp2.toString()},
        {v: temp4, f: temp1.toString()},
        {v: biggest, f: '0'}
      ]
    },
    chartArea: {
        left: '3.5%',
        width: '79%'
    },
    seriesType: 'bars',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    legend: 
    {
        alignment: 'center'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y'],
    // use object notation to provide formatted number for tooltip
    ['Test', {v: 1, f: '-1'}],
    ['Test', {v: 2, f: '-2'}],
    ['Test', {v: 3, f: '-3'}]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    vAxis: {
      ticks: [
        // use object notation to provide y-axis labels
        {v: 0, f: '0'},
        {v: 1, f: '-1'},
        {v: 2, f: '-2'},
        {v: 3, f: '-3'},
        {v: 4, f: '-4'}
      ]
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thats not quite what Im after, sorry if I didnt explain it well, I want the y axis to start at a higher number at the bottom and have 0 at the top like in the pictur i have attached but i don't want the bars to be upside down like in the picture. So the taller bars should have a value closer to 0

Comment: I was able to use your way to get what i wanted! Its a little more tricky as i dont know what the values will be as the chart is drawn dynamically, but i will have to come up with a way to do that! Thank you, I will add the picture to my question as im not sure i can in the comment

Comment: @AaronVance could you post your final solution?

Comment: @csy_dot_io I added code to the question, hope it helps, it is quite hard coded but is the best i could do

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll adapt it for my usecase.